# Android Fragment causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment

First going to say that I know there are a lot of similar posts to this, and I have seen them, however I am new to android development and am not yet familiar enough with it to modify those other answers to fix my exact problem.

I have a fragment that was created by default with a new project that contains a button and text view, and in my MainActivity.java i've made an onClick function for the button. This function throws the NPE. Here's the LogCat:

```
03-10 19:26:52.620: D/AndroidRuntime(878): Shutting down VM
03-10 19:26:52.620: W/dalvikvm(878): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2af2ba8)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878): Process: com.example.main, PID: 878 
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.main/com.example.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.example.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-10 19:26:52.630: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  ... 11 more
03-10 19:31:54.292: I/Process(878): Sending signal. PID: 878 SIG: 9
```

The MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.main;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
...

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new     PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        final TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myText.setText("Yes!");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking down the stack trace, it says there's a `NullPointerException` on line 31 of MainActivity.java.  If that isn't enough for you to figure it out, please tell us which line is line 31 in the listing.

Comment: myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

//right under the declaration for myButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `TextView` and the `Button` are in the layout's fragment, you need to find their id in the `onCreatedView` method of the fragment. Then, you should do:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        final TextView myText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Button myButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myText.setText("Yes!");
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

then myButton is null. so findViewById(R.id.button1) is returning null.  You should make sure that is the id you have used for the button your layout (R.layout.fragment_main)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any fetal mistakes in your `OnCreate` code but here are some hints to solve the problem

1) Make sure that your`activity` is initialized in the `Manifest.xml` file.

2) Try to run the project after commenting the `onClickListener` part to make sure that your problem is not in the inflation or in the `Layout` xml file itself.

3) Try to debug your`OnCreate` method and monitor all the different variable values by selecting the variable TO find out the problem

4) Make sure that your `button` and `TextView` are in the layout that you are inflating

I hope I could help

Answer (score -1):

The myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() line gives an exception because its done after you started the fragment, I believe. Put that code in the fragment constructor, and you should be good.